# SQL XML not returning data

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml

I am using the following code 
 It is not returning me results. What am i missing here?

```
    declare @iDoc INT           
  EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, '<Ids><Id Val ="40041">11</Id><Id Val ="40042">22</Id></Ids>'   
  Select @iDoc       
  Select Val FROM OPENXML (@iDoc, '/Ids/Id',2) WITH (Val varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Found answer - Replace  '/Ids/Id',2 with '/Ids/Id',5

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use xpath in the WITH part of the query.  This way, you don't need to worry about the 3rd parameter of the OPENXML function.  The following code works regardless of the 3rd parameter (it can be any value).

```
declare @iDoc INT           

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, '<Ids><Id Val ="40041">11</Id><Id Val ="40042">22</Id></Ids>'   

Select *
FROM   OPENXML (@iDoc, '/Ids/Id',2) 
WITH   (Val varchar(10) '@Val', 
       Id int '.')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @iDoc
```